# Android Studio - using webView.findAllAsync(text) to highlight text on website and then creating on click action on text

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app which have to find something in WebSite and then highlight it and create on click action on it.

I am looking for String "text" using this method:

```
private void searchInWebViewContent(String text){
    webView.findAllAsync(text);
}
```

This code should find all String "text" in webView and highlight them.

But... it doesn't highlight "text" when i run my app.

Second I am wondering how to create action listener on click on every highlighted String "text" that was found on the WebSite. I found this method when I was looking for it:

```
void setFindListener (WebView.FindListener listener){

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix my problems?
Waiting for replays. Cheers.

Ok the first one is working now:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (textToSearch != null && textToSearch != "") {
                    webview.findAllAsync(textToSearch);  // is not     supposed to crash
                    try {
                        Method m =     WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                        m.invoke(webview, true);
                    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String     url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (textToSearch != null && textToSearch != "") {
                    webview.findAllAsync(textToSearch);  // is not supposed to crash
// here i dont know how to create OnTouchListener on every textToSearch
//highlighted word. Here as an example I have just created it on webview
                    webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                                Intent myIntentActivity1 = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);
                                //call N_X and wait for result
                                startActivity(myIntentActivity1);

                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                        m.invoke(webview, true);
                    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            void setFindListener (WebView.FindListener listener)
            {

            }
```

How to create touch event on every word founded by findallasyc method?